# Give a Prove that the only consecutive no nulls integers numbers a, b, c

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Give a Prove that the only consecutive no nulls integers numbers a, b, c that satisfy the equality $a² + b² = c²$. are 3, 4, 5. -Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve for $n$ in $n^2+(n+1)^2=(n+2)^2$. We have, $n^2-2n-3=0$, gives $$n=\frac{2\pm \sqrt{4+12}}{2}$$
hence we can have $n=3,-1$, as all $a,b,c>0$ we have $n=3$ only. Hence, the only consecutive triple to satisfy the equation is $(3,4,5)$.

Comment: Oh dawm i already solved it the discrimant resulting from that equation k^2-2k-3=0, but i dont know it was the n=3 meaning. Shame on me.

Comment: But Thank you so much mate.

Answer (score 2):

Assume the consecutive numbers to be $m-1$, $m$, and $m+1$. Substitute in the equation given, and you will get your answer.

Comment: Hi teacher, well i have taken a=k, b=k+1, and c=k+2 for a k that belong to the integers. But i will try this. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @PaulTáctico It's possible to solve using your approach. Please explain your approach to the problem. See my answer.

Comment: When i solve for  $a²+b²=c²$ i finally have this k^2-2k=3. So honestly i not sure if these expresion prove that only 3,4,5 satisfy the equality. For that i come here. Thanks for answer to me mates.

Comment: @PaulTáctico Yes, your approach works. Solve the quadratic equation by completing the square, we get $(k-1)^2 = 4$. This gives $k=3,-1$. But, since you only want non-negative integers, we get $k=3$.

Comment: Yes @Ishan Deo i already prove it. the problem that i had was that i really was not sure if the K=3 result explain that only 3,4,5 satisfy the equality

Answer (score 0):

Consider the three consecutive numbers as $x-1,x,x+1$.

$(x-1)^2 + x^2 = (x+1)^2
x^2= 4x

One answer for the equation is x=0 and the other is x=4.
Two possible consecutive number sets solves the equation.

-1,0,1 and 3,4,5.

Since you are looking for non-null integers only 3,4,5 are the consecutive numbers that  satisfy the equation.$

Comment: Thank for your answer mate. I already prove it.

Answer (score 0):

If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are consecutuve integers, then $c-a=2$ and $c+a=2b$.

If $a^2+b^2=c^2$, then $b^2=(c+a)(c-a)=2b(2)$ $\implies$ $b=4$

Answer (score 0):

Option:

$a^2=c^2-b^2=(c-b)(c+b)$.

Set $a=n; b=n+1; c=n+2$;

$n^2= (2n+3)$;

$n^2-2n -3=0$;

$(n-3)(n+1)=0$.

$n=3$; discard $n=-1$.

Comment: Thank for your answer mate. I already prove it.

Comment: Paul Tactico. Welcome.